# Which approach is better to handle HTTP (rest PHP+MYSQL structure) with Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, android-volley

I have started a new personal project in which I am doing an app for Android with database handling. I am currently doing the login process and I have a few questions before starting to code.

1. I read that using a RESTful service is the best way to handle databases, at least is was said to be the safest. Java makes the HTTP connection with the PHP file in my server and the PHP file executes the MYSQL sentence. Is this true? Are there more safe options?
2. At the time of making the HTTP requests, I saw few options: Volley library, Retrofit library, RxJava with Retrofit and using Asynctask with Java and Apache basic libraries (as it can be seen in this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql)
3. I also saw in a Volley tutorial that the data is converted to JSON. Let's say I am not fetching entire rows or column. It is useless then to use JSON? I know that for the sake of future JSON object would be something accesible for everyone, but given is a personal project I could even make a split(",") script to retrieve the data.

For example; if I make a JSON object I would have to write "[key] Result: [pair] fail/ok" if I make a simple retrieve of the String object I would get "Failed" or "Success" directly.

Does it make sense what I am trying to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to make sure you understand what is web service before you create your own web service.

The web service can be achieved by many efficient micro frameworks. For example do some research on Slim PHP, Laravel's lumen, etc. This will process the request sent from Android App, process the data & sends back response to the App. While processing, you will have to fetch data or make changes in the database.

Considering android app, you can choose default http client or third party libraries like Okhttp3, retrofit, volley etc. These are the clients to call the web service & get the response from the server.  Next part is to choose request &response body. This can be JSON, XML etc. JSON is recommended. To handle this JSON response, you default JSON parser to use GSON library.

Have a look at the Weather API by Yahoo, it's a free web service you can call, and is quite well documented. You can find the web service calls & JSON examples here. https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html

You have quite a broad set of requirements in your question, please try what I've recommended then come back with refined further questions

Good luck!